# Django. Doing complex calculations in database

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's part of my model file :

```
class Metric(models.Model):
    Team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    metric_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.metric_name


class Members(models.Model):
    Metric = models.ForeignKey(Metric, through="Calculate")
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40, null=True, blank=True)
    week_one = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    week_two = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    week_three = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    week_four = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.member_ID

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.total = int(self.week_one)+int(self.week_two)+int(self.week_three)+int(self.week_four)
            super(Members, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Now what I want to do is. I want to calculate the number of members per metric the aggregate total of all the members in a metric and the highest total among all the members in a metric.

I can't figure out a way to do this in Django.
I want to make these calculations and store them in the database.
Can anyone please help me out with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to "memoize" these results, there are at least two paths that you could follow:

1. A per-row post-save trigger on the Members table that updates "members_count", "members_total" and "members_max" fields in the Metric table.

   The challenge with this is in maintaining the trigger creation DDL alongside the rest of your code and applying it automatically whenever the models are re-created or altered.

   The Django ORM does not make this especially easy. The commonest migration tool ( south ) also doesn't go out of its way to make this easy. Also note that this solution will be specific to one RDBMS and that some RDBMSs may not support this.
2. You could create "synthetic" fields in your Metric model then use a post-save signal handler to update them whenever a Member is added or changed.

   ```
   class Metric(models.Model):
       Team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
       metric_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)

       members_count = models.IntegerField()
       members_max = models.IntegerField()
       members_total = models.IntegerField()

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.metric_name

   # signal handling
   from django.db.models import signals
   from django.dispatch import dispatcher

   def members_post_save(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
       # Update the count, max, total fields
       met = sender.Metric # sender is an instance of Members
       metric.members_count = Members.objects.filter(Metric=met).count()
       # more code here to do the average etc;

   dispatcher.connect(members_post_save, signal=signals.post_save, sender=Members)
   ```

The django signals documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) can be of use.

**Caveats**

1. While this sort of approach could be made to achieve your stated goal, it is brittle. You need to have test coverage that ensures that this signal handler always fires, even after you've done some refactoring of your code.
2. I would also consider using "related objects" queries [ documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects ] eg, assuming we have a "me" instance of Metric

   ```
   >> members_count = me.members_set.count()
   >> # aggregation queries for the total and max
   ```

If these aggregates are not used very often, path #2 could be a viable and more maintainable option.